Reset Rosetta Flag for Desktop App
A little bit of background: If you make an app with no compiled Arm64 binaries in the Content/MacOS folder, MacOS erroneously identifies it as an Intel based app. After launching the app, MacOS will prompt the user to install rosetta, despite the app running fine natively. I found a simple solution to this issue, either include a do-nothing compiled binary to Contents/MacOS, or add
    <key>LSArchitecturePriority</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>

to the plist. I posted the solution here Shell script application bundle prompts for Rosetta installation
The problem is this change only fixes the issue if you also change the BundleID. If you run the app even once with the bad configuration, MacOS seems to cache the intel flag somewhere based on the BundleID. It does not seem to be cached in the usual places.
How to reproduce: (On apple silicon)

You probably already have rosetta, and it is a pain to remove, so a VM is likely needed.
Make an empty app with Script Editor, export with file format: Application.
Replace Example.app/Content/MacOS/applet with a script of the same name. Make sure the old applet is gone, don't rename it and leave it in the directory. I used:

#!/usr/bin/osascript
display dialog "Hello, world"


Make it executable sudo chmod +x ./Example.app/Content/MacOS/applet
Run example.app and observe that it asks you to install rosetta
Add the previously mentioned fix to you plist, including the BundleID change
Run it again and observe that it now works
Change your BundleID back. Running this now raises the rosetta prompt despite the fact that it runs fine on a clean install of MacOS.

Things I have tried:

Rebooting, no effect
Reforming the app, no effect
Reboot in recovery mode, no effect
lsregister -delete, no effect
~/Library/Preferences, ~/Library/Caches, /Library/Preferences, and /Library/Caches, none contain an entry for the BundleId
defaults delete, domain not found
signing app, no effect
clearing /var/db/oah, it is already empty

I am not great with MacOS so it is possible I am overlooking something simple.

Select the app in the Finder and open the Get Info window (command-I). If there is a checkbox in the window labeled "Open in Rosetta", uncheck it. Otherwise you'll have to reset the LaunchServices database.

@LincD. I do not see the checkbox. ill try launch-services

@LincD. I reset launch services, and even went so far as to lsregister --delete and reboot. But the issue persists

So this is for a shell script executable? Does the shell get run as Arm64? In other words, if Rosetta gets installed, but not used, does it matter?

@benwiggy I am unsure how to check if it is arm64 or not, but it does matter, as it appears to any end user that the app isn't made for arm. I would imagine it has to be arm, I don't think arm macos has binaries for intel shell.

This may have something to do with the fact that Apple Silicon apps need a valid codesignature to run. Run codesign -vv to check the validity of the signature. If it has an ad-hoc signature, re-sign it with your Developer ID from Apple (assuming you have one.)

@LincD. Yes, the issue persists after signing and verifying.

Rosetta caches data in /var/db/oah. Try deleting that.

@LincD. I booted into recovery, disabled SIP, rebooted, and now that I can view /var/db/oah, it is empty. Still requires rosetta. This is likely because rosetta isn't actually installed. I'll add these to the 'Things I tried' list in the question.

What I would do in your place is create and launch an ARM-only app with the problem BID and accept the prompt to install Rosetta. Since the app can't actually run in Rosetta, you'll either get an error message or it will launch natively (or both). Whatever bit was squirreled away somwhere before should then be reset. You can remove Rosetta if it's really important to you to do that, but it doesn't take up much space and could come in handy sometimes.
